# Replace null cell with space character

Tags: openrefine

In a certain column, I am trying to replace any cell with a null value with a single space. I am trying to combine multiple rows where each row only contains one letter.  When I join multi-valued cells, Refine will (understandably) throw out the null values, resulting in a large string of text with no spaces between words.

I have found several articles describing how to delete rows with null cells, but not add a space to null cells.

fwiw, below is the article I followed to join multi-valued cells
http://onlinejournalismblog.com/2014/05/30/how-to-combine-multiple-rows-in-a-dataset-where-text-is-split-across-them-open-refine/#more-18955

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use join multi-valued cells Refine ask you what separator you wish to use. The default is `,` (comma space). You can edit this to be a single space.

Alternatively did you try to create a text facet and bulk edit the `(blank)` value with a single space before using join multi-valued cells?

Comment: Thanks! Creating a text facet and bulk editing the (blank) value worked.  I had tried the former suggestion, but since each one of my cells contained a single letter instead of a single word, it inserted a space between e v e r y l e t t e r .